# Python to chart.js

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, chart.js

I have sqlite database with single table. I am trying to read data with Python and pandas and return the data as json file in a function. Then the goal is to use Javascript to fetch the json data and use it for chart.js.

Here is my Python Code that should read the data form the database:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def chart_data(self):
    cnx = sqlite3.connect('Production.db', check_same_thread=False)
    daily_df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM data_object", cnx)

    return daily_df.to_json()
```

Then here is the part of the JavaScript code that I am trying to use to fetch data from that python call:

```
    function get_chart_data() {
    fetch('/chart_data').then( x => {
    return x.json();
    }).then( x => {
    console.log(x);
    });
    }
```

In this instance i am trying to print the data in console.log just to see if i am getting data from Python. However I need this data to be fed into chart.js

```
  var data = {
  labels: [],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Dataset",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    borderWidth: 2,
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    data: [],
  }]
};

var options = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      gridLines: {
        display: true,
        color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
      }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      }
    }]
  }
};

Chart.Bar('chart', {
  options: options,
  data: data
});
```

And finally, the sqilite table has these columns:timestamp,capacity,max_capacity, true_count.
There is only 24 rows of data,  one for each hour of the day.

And here is where I am stuck. I am not sure how to properly pull this data into the chart. The goal is to plot true count over the 24h period.

With the code I have so far I know i am very close but i am missing something to make this work.
Am I pulling the data properly with javascript from python?
And how do i then push that json data in javascript into label variable and data variable in chart.js?

I have made some progress. I am now able to get data to javascript console log while using your ajax example.

```
    /* chart.js chart examples */

$(document).ready(function(){
   var _data;
   var _labels;
  $.ajax({
   url: "chart_data",
   type: "get",
   success: function(response) {
     full_data = JSON.parse(response);
     _data = full_data['true_count'];
     _labels = full_data['timestamp'];
   },

 });

// chart colors
var colors = ['#007bff','#28a745','#333333','#c3e6cb','#dc3545','#6c757d'];

/* large line chart */
var chLine = document.getElementById("chLine");
var chartData = {
  labels:_labels,
  datasets: [
  {
    data:_data,
    backgroundColor: [
                          'rgba(42, 157, 244, 0.1)'
                      ],
                      borderColor: [
                          'rgba(42, 157, 244, 1)',
                          'rgba(33, 145, 81, 0.2)',
                      ],
                      borderWidth: 1
  }]
};

if (chLine) {
  new Chart(chLine, {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false
        }
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
  });
}



;
});
```

So if i do console.log(full_data) i get my data from python in json format as i wanted. However, i am getting error that says:  full_data is not defined at the line where I am saying that labels: full_data['timestamp']

It seems that my full data is not accessable from the chart block. I am sure i am misplacing few brackets to make this work but I am unable to figure out where.
Any ideas?

My json file looks like this:

[{"timestamp":"00:00:00.000000","true_count":0},{"timestamp":"01:00:00.000000","true_count":0},{"timestamp":"02:00:00.000000","true_count":0},{"timestamp":"03:00:00.000000","true_count":0},{"timestamp":"04:00:00.000000","true_count":0},{"timestamp":"05:00:00.000000","true_count":0},{"timestamp":"06:00:00.000000","true_count":2},{"timestamp":"07:00:00.000000","true_count":5},{"timestamp":"08:00:00.000000","true_count":7},{"timestamp":"09:00:00.000000","true_count":8},{"timestamp":"10:00:00.000000","true_count":12},{"timestamp":"11:00:00.000000","true_count":15},{"timestamp":"12:00:00.000000","true_count":20},{"timestamp":"13:00:00.000000","true_count":17},{"timestamp":"14:00:00.000000","true_count":14},{"timestamp":"15:00:00.000000","true_count":13},{"timestamp":"16:00:00.000000","true_count":11},{"timestamp":"17:00:00.000000","true_count":19},{"timestamp":"18:00:00.000000","true_count":22},{"timestamp":"19:00:00.000000","true_count":16},{"timestamp":"20:00:00.000000","true_count":14},{"timestamp":"21:00:00.000000","true_count":10},{"timestamp":"22:00:00.000000","true_count":7},{"timestamp":"23:00:00.000000","true_count":4}]

I have been trying to parse this so timestamp goes to _labels and true_count goes to _data but no luck.

Here is what i have:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
   var _data =[];
   var _labels = [];
  $.ajax({
   url: "chart_data",
   type: "get",
   success: function(response) {
     full_data = JSON.parse(response);
    full_data.forEach(function(key,index){
        _data = key.true_count;
        _labels= key.timestamp;
        
    });
     //_data = [full_data['true_count']];
     //_labels = [full_data['timestamp']];
   },

 });
```

Any suggestion what am I doing wrong now?

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing my example which I used using **Google charts** .I am fetching live data from **OPC Server** using ajax and updated my real-time graph. It won't be a big difference if you use database instead of opc server. I hope you can relate it with your example.

**Html**

```
<div class="row" id="grap">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="chart-wrapper">
                      <div id="graph"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is django file from where I am passing data to **gettemp()** function via ajax call in json format. In your case it is database and there wont be issue.
**Views.py**

```
def plcdata(request):
    url="opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:9000"
    client=Client(url)
    client.connect()
    print("Client Connected")
    data={}
    dt=[]
    while True:
        pres=client.get_node("ns=2;i=2")
        Pressure=pres.get_value()
        adp=client.get_node("ns=2;i=3")
        ap=adp.get_value()
        rh=client.get_node("ns=2;i=4")
        r=rh.get_value()
        sp=client.get_node("ns=2;i=5")
        s=sp.get_value()
        nitro=client.get_node("ns=2;i=6")
        n=nitro.get_value()
        o2n=client.get_node("ns=2;i=7")
        o=o2n.get_value()
        hgl=client.get_node("ns=2;i=8")
        h=hgl.get_value()
        stempress=client.get_node("ns=2;i=9")
        sps=stempress.get_value()
        cond=client.get_node("ns=2;i=10")
        co=cond.get_value()
        dmwp=client.get_node("ns=2;i=11")
        dmp=dmwp.get_value()
        dmwf=client.get_node("ns=2;i=12")
        dmf=dmwf.get_value()
        chwp=client.get_node("ns=2;i=13")
        chp=chwp.get_value()
        chwt=client.get_node("ns=2;i=14")
        cht=chwt.get_value()
        icp=client.get_node("ns=2;i=16")
        ip=icp.get_value()
        icf=client.get_node("ns=2;i=15")
        iff=icf.get_value()
        ict=client.get_node("ns=2;i=17")
        it=ict.get_value()
        dcpp=client.get_node("ns=2;i=19")
        dpp=dcpp.get_value()
        dcff=client.get_node("ns=2;i=18")
        dff=dcff.get_value()
        dctt=client.get_node("ns=2;i=20")
        dtt=dctt.get_value()
        #Time=client.get_node("ns=2;i=3")
        #Ti=Time.get_value()
        #Ti1=datetime.time(Ti.hour,Ti.minute,Ti.second)

        ti=datetime.now()
        ti1=(str(ti.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
        dt.append(str(Pressure)+','+ti1+','+str(ap)+','+str(r)+','+str(s)+','+str(n)+','+str(o)+','+str(h)+','+str(sps)+','+str(co)+','+str(dmp)+','+str(dmf)+','+str(chp)+','+str(cht)+','+str(ip)+','+str(it)+','+str(iff)+','+str(dpp)+','+str(dtt)+','+str(dff))
        data['final']=dt
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Please check the **getTemp()** function as data is recieved from django in the success function. This is the part where you will have to make changes as per your requirement.

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('graph'));
    var options = {'title' : 'CTL-2 AIR PRESSURE (Bar)',    
    titleTextStyle: {
        fontName: "Arial", 
        fontSize: 18, 
    },
      animation: {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'out',
        startup: true
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Time',
        format: "HH:mm:ss",

        textStyle: {
          fontSize : 14,
          bold:'true',
        },
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Air Pressure',
        format: '0.00',
        textStyle: {
          fontSize : 14,
          bold:'true',
        },
      },
      height: 450,
      width:1000,
      legend:'bottom'
    };
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Air Pressure');

    var go=[];
    function getTemp() {

          $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"{% url 'plcdata' %}",
        success:function(dat){
            for(i=0;i<dat.final.length;i++){
                var go=dat.final[i].split(',');
                var tm = new Date();
                if(data.hg.length>15){
                  data.removeRow(0);
                }                 
                data.addRow([tm, Number(go[0])]);
                chart.draw(data, options);

            }
            return dat;
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("Error Occurred");
        }
    })
    }

    getTemp();
    setInterval(getTemp, 3000);

  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
</script>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMWVB.png
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I waa hoping to use Fetch function instead of Ajax. And I think you are using different methodology to get to data even with Ajax by posting it into html variable. I am trying to get much simpler solution.

Comment: @Slavisha84 sorry but there is no html table here. my **data** and yours data variable is same. The only differnce is that my data is handled by google charts itself whereas in your case you can modify your data in chartjs as per your request which would make it more easier for you. and there is no fetch function in google charts. and mines is a real time live graph. I just wanted to show you as an example

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try to see if i can use your example with my code.

Comment: @Slavisha84 Sure if you face any issues please do let me know..we will try it out

Comment: I made good progress and i think i just need one more hint to make this works. Can you please take a look my updated comment?

Comment: @Slavisha84 As you are storing `fulldate['timestamp']` in `_labels` variable which is global. Why are you calling local variable `fulldate['timestamp']` in `label` .You should call `_labels` in `label` as it is global. Same for `fulldate['truecount']` .You should call `_data` in your `data`. If my answer was helpful to you please accept it so that it may help others in future. If any other errors you are facing, we can discuss it out

Comment: I updated script per your last suggestion. For some reason when i do console.log(full_data) i get the json and i can see the data, but when i try to print out console.log(_label) or console.log(_data) I am getting error: "VM1063:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: _labels is not defined"

Comment: @Slavisha84 Yes because `_labels` and `_data` are just variables. but you want to store it as array as you are recieving json array format from your views.py. Please check my `go` variable which I used in my example